# Searching and printing multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Wondering if I can have some direction and clarity in what I need to do. I am taking an input (text input) and searching a CSV file which I can convert to an array.

I have figured out to search it with this:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($csv, 0), $SearchThis);
```

Where `$csv` is my array (multidimensional), and `$SearchThis` is the input to search for.

My problem is that `$keys` makes an array with values of which row that data was found in.

I want to be able to display a table with those rows out of the main array `$csv`. (Each row has a list of data that will be displayed on the table.)

I am fairly new to PHP, so I hope this is an easy fix?

*Any* help would be greatly appreciated. Especially the logic behind taking rows from the arrays etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your code is returning the correct rows already, then all you need to do is filter the array to contain only those rows.  For example:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($csv, 0), $SearchThis);  // Your original code
$new_csv = [];                                           // [] is shorthand for an empty array.
foreach($keys as $index) {                               // Iterate over the keys
    $new_csv[] = $csv[$index];                           // Copy the matching rows to our new array
}
```

`$new_csv` will now contain only the matching rows from the original now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$csv` is an array that is of the type

```
[
   [ cell1, cell2, ... ],
   ...
]
```

Then you would probably want an [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for each row in the CSV with a callback that returns true to include to row, and false to exclude the row:

```
$searchStr = '123';
array_filter($csv, function( $row ) use ( &$searchStr ) {
   return $row[0] == $searchStr;
});
```